# Getting 'undefined' when trying to display user input a second time

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm making a word-guessing game for a javascript course. The user gets five guesses to identify a word, and I want the input to be displayed back to the user for every guess. Made a field of 5 * 5 squares, words to be displayed horizontally after the user makes his/her guess.

I've got the first row working, and thought it'd be easy to use the same code for the next four rows, but I'm getting 'undefined' instead of the actual letters in the second row. I'm sure I'm missing something trivial, but can't figure out what it is. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Here's the html:

```
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter 5 letters"><button>1st Guess</button></td>
        <td id="hiddenPointBox"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter 5 letters"><button>2nd Guess</button></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

And the javascript:

```
var words = ["apple", "lemon", "melon", "grape", "peach"];                         
var currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];                            
console.log(currentWord);    

var guessCheck = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];                       
guessCheck.addEventListener("click", function() {                                  
  var guessWord = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;                 
  var letterDisplay = document.getElementsByTagName("td");                         
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                                                    
    letterDisplay[i].innerHTML = guessWord[i];                                     
    if (guessWord[i] === currentWord[i]) {                                         
      letterDisplay[i].style.background = "#00ff25";                               
    } else {                                                                       
      letterDisplay[i].style.background = "#ff0000";                               
    }                                                                              
  }                                                                                

  if (guessWord.length < 5) {                                                      
    alert("You have to enter exactly 5 characters!");                              
  }                                                                                
})
```

Here's where I started to repeat the code:

```
var guessCheck = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];                       
guessCheck.addEventListener("click", function() {                               
  var guessWordRowTwo = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;        
  var letterDisplay = document.getElementsByTagName("td");                      
  for(var i = 7; i < 12; i++) {                                                 
    letterDisplay[i].innerHTML = guessWordRowTwo[i];                            
    if (guessWordRowTwo[i] === currentWord[i]) {                                
      letterDisplay[i].style.background = "#00ff25";                            
    } else {                                                                    
      letterDisplay[i].style.background = "#ff0000";                            
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
  if (guessWordRowTwo.length < 5) {                                             
    alert("You have to enter exactly 5 characters!");                           
  }                                                                             
})
```

Comment: What exactly is it telling you is undefined?  You have a few unusual references that could be causing it, such as guessWord[i] (when guessword appears to be a string not an array).  Also, avoid things like var guessCheck = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0], they get confusing and break easily.  Add an html id and retrieve it that way so it's much clearer what you are returning.

Comment: Sorry, could have been a bit more precise I guess. The undefined data was the user input I intended to be displayed in the td cells.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong indexes for `guessWordRowTwo` and `currentWord`.

This should work for you

```
guessCheck.addEventListener("click", function() {    
    var guessWordRowTwo = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;       
    var letterDisplay = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    console.log(guessWordRowTwo);
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
        letterDisplay[i+7].innerHTML = guessWordRowTwo[i];

        if (guessWordRowTwo[i] === currentWord[i]) {        
            letterDisplay[i+7].style.background = "#00ff25";    
        }
        else {        
            letterDisplay[i+7].style.background = "#ff0000";        
        }    
    }
    if (guessWordRowTwo.length < 5) {
        alert("You have to enter exactly 5 characters!");
    }
})
```

Anyway I suggest you to check inputs as soon as possible

```
Check.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var guessWordRowTwo = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
    if (guessWordRowTwo.length < 5) {
        alert("You have to enter exactly 5 characters!");
    }
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet is accessing the array wrong. Your words (`input.value`) are 5 characters length and you are trying to get from 7 to 11.

Also you need to modify the cells in the corresponding row:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Trying to keep your code as much as possible you can fix it like this:

```
var guessCheck = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];                       
guessCheck.addEventListener("click", function() {                               
  var guessWordRowTwo = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
  // CHANGED        
  var letterDisplay = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].getElementsByTagName("td");
  // CHANGED                      
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                                                 
    letterDisplay[i].innerHTML = guessWordRowTwo[i];                            
    if (guessWordRowTwo[i] === currentWord[i]) {                                
      letterDisplay[i].style.background = "#00ff25";                            
    } else {                                                                    
      letterDisplay[i].style.background = "#ff0000";                            
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
  if (guessWordRowTwo.length < 5) {                                             
    alert("You have to enter exactly 5 characters!");                           
  }                                                                             
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qb38tk8j/).

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was going for! I didn't know you could access two elements simultaneously. Thought I could get around it by retrieving cells 7-11 that way, but obviously that wasn't the way to go about it. Thanks again!